# Creating a sub-type and sub-class from a struct definition

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to write a class that is able to take a struct definition and generate a type and class definition to be used like a regular class.

I think that an optimal result would be something like this (although I'm flexible as my greater target is to parse and use a struct in TS):

```js
interface TestFields {
    hello: 'a',
}

interface BooFields {
    world: Struct<TestFields>,
    wow: 'b'
}

export const TestStruct = Struct.define<TestFields>({
    hello: 'a'
});

export const BooStruct = Struct.define<BooFields>({
    world: TestStruct,
    wow: 'b'
});

let myVar = new BooStruct();
myVar.wow = 1;
myVar.world.hello = 4;
```

A very slimmed down version of the code that I'm trying:

```js
export type FieldTypes = 'a' | 'b';
export type NestedFieldTypes = FieldTypes | Struct<any>;

export interface FieldDefinition {
    type: NestedFieldTypes;
    name: string;
    offset: number;
}

export type StructFields<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Struct<infer U>
        ? U
        : FieldTypes;
};


export class Struct<T extends StructFields<T>> {
        public static readonly TypeSizes: { [K in FieldTypes]: number } = {
        a: 1,
        b: 2
    };

    public static readonly FieldDefinitions: FieldDefinition[] = [];

    public get length(): number {
        return 1;
    }

    constructor() {}

    public static define<T extends StructFields<T>>(fields: T): typeof Struct<T> {
        const fieldDefinitions: FieldDefinition[] = [];

        let currentOffset = 0;

        for (const name in fields) {
            const fieldType = fields[name];

            // if (fieldType instanceof Struct) {
            //     currentOffset += (fieldType as Struct<any>).length;
            //     fieldDefinitions.push({ type: new (fieldType as Struct<T>)(), name: name, offset: currentOffset });
            // } else if (Array.isArray(fieldType) && fieldType.every(value => value instanceof Struct)) {
            //  for (const nestedStruct of fieldType) {
            //      currentOffset += nestedStruct.length;
            //  }
            // } else {
                currentOffset += Struct.TypeSizes[fieldType as FieldTypes];
                fieldDefinitions.push({ type: fieldType, name: name, offset: currentOffset });
            // }
        }

        let result = Struct<T>;
        result.FieldDefinitions.push(...fieldDefinitions);

        return result;
    }
}
```

I tried playing around with/without `typeof Struct<X>` in various places
Also I removed the `Struct<X>[]` implementation cause it added complexity (hence the commented out code)

My problems are either that the result of the `define` function is an object and not a class or that I can't define the `type` in `fieldDefinitions` to `fieldType`

**EDIT**: I'd like to give a bit more context. When I say "struct", I mean a C struct. The script is intended for frida so `wow` could be of type `"uint32"` and accept only values of `number`

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean by "struct" here?  Since this is a TypeScript/JavaScript question and not, say, C, you should probably be explicit about what you mean.  How do I interpret `{hello: "a"}` in such a way that `var.hello=4` makes sense?  What's the relationship between `a` and `4` here?

Comment: I've updated the question.
a more accurate example would be `{hello: "int32"}` and `var.hello=4` is valid while `var.hello="world"` is invalid

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZV4Em) the sort of thing you're looking for? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing

Comment: woooooooo this is amazing!
I'd love for you to explain as much as you can - js/ts ability to bend always surprises me (and the immensely deep knowledge of people around it)

Comment: So is that more or less what you’re looking for? Once I write up an answer I probably won’t want to change it too much, so if there’s any part that doesn’t work how you want, please tell me now before I start writing. (Actually anytime in the next ~8 hours is fine, since it’s now my bedtime.  I’ll come back when I wake up.)

Comment: I'm testing the cases of `myVar.haha = [ new TestStruct(), new TestStruct() ];` and `myVar.asdf = [ 1, 23, 555 ];` with a BooStruct `const BooStruct = Structify({
    world: TestStruct,
    haha: [TestStruct],
    asdf: ['int64'],
    wow: 'int64'
})`

Comment: while I've ended up with code that works, ts keeps failing type checks (I end up always returning never)

Comment: figured it out! `
        { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends keyof FieldMap ? K : never]: FieldMap[T[K]] } &
        { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends (keyof FieldMap)[] ? K : never]: FieldMap[Flatten<T[K]>][] } &
        { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends FieldCtor<any> ? K : never]: T[K] extends new () => infer O ? O : never } &
        { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends FieldCtor<any>[] ? K : never]: T[K] extends (new () => infer O)[] ? O[] : never }`

Comment: I’m confused about what’s happening in these comments: if you have a use case you need the answer to address, please [edit] the question to describe it.  Right now my plan is still to write up my original answer and trust that you can modify it to meet your needs (or open a new question post if you can’t). Does that sound okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will sketch an implementation of a *class [factory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming))* called `Structify()` that takes a schema object describing the desired shape of the class, and produces a new class constructor corresponding to it.  The reason why we need a schema object and not just a type is because, at runtime, [TypeScript types have already been *erased*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types).  So we need an actual value.  Luckily the type can be inferred from that value, so we won't need to repeat ourselves.

The desired behavior will look something like this:

```
const TestStruct = Structify({
    hello: 'uint32'
});

const BooStruct = Structify({
    world: TestStruct,
    wow: 'int64'
})

let myVar = new BooStruct();
/* let myVar: {
    world: {
        hello?: number | undefined;
    };
    wow?: number | undefined;
} */

myVar.wow = 1;
myVar.world.hello = 4;

console.log(myVar instanceof BooStruct) // true
console.log(myVar.world instanceof TestStruct) // true
```

As you can see, the schema object's properties are either a string like `"uint32"` corresponding to some known field type, or a zero-arg class constructor like `TestStruct`.  Also note that for those known field types, the resulting class fields are [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties); that's because there's no *default* value for the fields (at least in my implementation), so if you just write `new TestStruct()`, the `hello` property will start off undefined.  So instead of `{hello: number}` we have `{hello?: number}`.

---

Okay, let's implement it.  First we need a type describing the known fields, like this:

```
interface FieldMap {
    uint32: number;
    int64: number;
    string: string;
}
```

You can add or change the fields as desired.  Note that I am not planning to have any runtime validation of the types to see that, for example, `"uint32"` is non-negative and in the appropriate range.  If you want that you'll have to modify the implementation.

Okay, here goes:

```
function Structify<
    T extends Record<keyof T, (new () => any) | keyof FieldMap>
>(schema: T) {

    type O = (
        { [K in keyof T]?: unknown } &
        { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends keyof FieldMap ? K : never]?:
            FieldMap[T[K]] } &
        { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends keyof FieldMap ? never : K]:
            T[K] extends new () => infer O ? O : never }
    ) extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;

    return class {
        constructor() {
            Object.entries(schema).forEach(([k, v]: [string, any]) => {
                if (typeof v === "function") (this as any)[k] = new v();
            }
            )
        }
    } as new () => O;
}
```

This function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type parameter `T` corresponding to the `schema` input.  It is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) so that each property is either a zero-arg [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) or a key of `FieldMap`.

Inside the function we compute the type `O` corresponding to the instance type of the output class.  It's kind of messy, but the point is that we [map](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the properties of `T`, and for each property that's a key of `FieldMap` we make an optional property whose type is the corresponding value of `FieldMap`; while for each property that's a constructor, we make a required property whose type is the instance type of that constructor.

The particular implementation uses [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) and [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to construct `O` in such a way that the output is as "pretty" as I can make it.  It's similar to something like

```
type O = { [K in keyof T]:
    T[K] extends keyof FieldMap ?
    FieldMap[T[K]] | undefined :
    T[K] extends new () => infer O ? O : never
}
```

which might be easier to comprehend, although in this case the `FieldMap` properties are not optional (although they do allow `undefined`).

Anyway, the function implementation returns a [class expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class) whose constructor takes no arguments.  That constructor initializes the class instance by invoking any constructors in from `config` and assigning the resulting object to the corresponding property of the class instance (which is `this`).  Note that there are multiple [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and uses of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) to loosen the type checking.  That's because the compiler cannot possibly understand the logic to verify that the implementation's retyrn value matches the complicated generic conditional return type.  So we have to be careful that the implementation is correct.

---

Okay, let's test it out.  The stuff with `TestStruct` and `BooStruct` above works as expected.  Let me try a different example:

```
const Person = Structify({
    name: "string",
    age: "int64",
})

const PairOfPeople = Structify({
    person1: Person,
    person2: Person
})
```

So a `Person` should have (optional) `name` and `age` properties, and a `PairOfPeople` has two `Person` properties.  Does it?

```
const people = new PairOfPeople();
/* const people: {
    person1: {
        name?: string | undefined;
        age?: number | undefined;
    };
    person2: {
        name?: string | undefined;
        age?: number | undefined;
    };
} */
people.person1.name = "John";
people.person1.age = 35;
people.person2.name = "Jane";
people.person2.age = 30;
console.log(people)
/* {
  "person1": {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 35
  },
  "person2": {
    "name": "Jane",
    "age": 30
  }
} */
```

Yes, looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLAgGwCYFk4AOyA3gLABQyVyArqGAMwBMAXMiDQLYBG0A3BWrJ6ANgAsbDj36DqAZzBRQAczYKlIZQPIBfCvvIwaIBGGAB7EMgDKimqeAwAngB5ZVACrIIAD0ghsOWQAJQgEcyhsFwBrCCdzGGQPABpkAAoQCAB3dIBKZABeAD5kOBAnfIAfZFj4xPQsPEIiiiK0uQQACwhOODYPfLJyd2QwJwIUAHlC9JGhYmQAbQBpYStahKSAXQB+NmNokHMsqx1kADI56gWVtZq4za84II8Vre8-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-ZBmMYgxiLIqAQw0mYAEZtAs8jrPg7AQ1E8wZjEP9yAPcwCJDJ9lDSRypVABQyiQTYaJQ-JGMY0Yzwgf83T8iAAvMIKQucgTsDWcKTAgR4kJi5A4oSmgktNZLDwABWgORLAgs8oJvXiQDgTgIDYZt800Zs0NlOBlC6lssP6788OqjiargYAoEmGA6vMAgCKaq9oN4iYoAakBbLYOrtssAahC2nbWGQA6domgwDw42sVpQSichmuaFqWh6GPIFiXQAu7CoeniRlOyw9qE512s68TeuUXTaH0hTMiM4TqCGiAtMkhk9LkhGlLU6U8eBkBzt4oQIbRtQI00WHZIMxG8aEVH0ekaS4exwy8Z0HcTLM8h7v8wnbJDMmZmbAApcxOhAZttD5tKBZDVGZgYABWGX-v5+rLCYIWOseltRbKCBpYoWWQ0J7XFabBgAAZtF8-zArSWW8O+8tmwF5tAdlZsyc9-WJal47qGbVG-ZV2QdCD93NaJv3eJ93W-bFw3xu90O2BtiPjNMiggA)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
I'd also like to be able to add methods to the new instances so that I can do `people.person.grow()` or `people.spawn()`
I tried subclassing the anonymous class but ts didn't like this at all
should I open a new question?

Comment: Like [this maybe](https://tsplay.dev/NBVRxN)?  If that doesn't suffice then you might want to open a new question.  Good luck!

Comment: exactly! you're the best...